# CC Suggesting Redundant Ensures

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I have a piece of code which looks a little like this:

```
public TReturn SubRegion(TParam foo)
{
    Contract.Requires(foo!= null);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<TReturn>() != null);

    if (!CheckStuff(foo))
        foo.Blah();
    return OtherStuff(foo);
}
```

CC is giving me a warning:

> Warning 301 CodeContracts: Consider adding the postcondition Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result() != null); to provide extra-documentation to the library clients

Which is obviously completely redundant! I have several such redundant warnings and it's becoming a problem (real warnings getting buried in a torrent of redundant suggestions).

So I have two questions:

1) Am I missing something which means this is not a redundant recommendation? In which case what do I need to do to fix this warning?

2) Alternatively, if this is just a quirk of CCCheck and cannot be fixed how can I hide or suppress this warning?

N.b. Just in case you think my example is missing something important, the full code is the *SubRegion* method [here](https://bitbucket.org/martindevans/base-citygeneration/src/bdaf76ce23d5febd0f472038cd56e4e3699d9fbe/Base-CityGeneration/Utilities/BasePolygonRegion.cs?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#BasePolygonRegion.cs-291).

Comment: Which version of code contracts are you using?

Comment: Looking at your code, I think the problem is further down the line. In `SubRegion` there is a call to `ConstructFromSlicePart`, which in turn has a call to `Construct(IReadOnlyList<Side> shape)`. Inside `Construct` the last line is `return default(TSection)`. If `TSection` is a reference type, then the method will return null. This could be the cause, which ultimately is manifesting itself as this warning.

Comment: CC version is 1.9.10714.2 - as far as I can see that's the latest. re: construct method, are you sure you weren't looking in the contracts class? The only real implementation of Construct is this: https://bitbucket.org/martindevans/base-citygeneration/src/0128578a6228487ac3d98398bf0c8ed8bb43d0f5/Base-CityGeneration/Elements/Building/Internals/Floors/Design/Region.cs?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#Region.cs-34 which obviously never returns null!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding 2: The [documentation](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/userdoc.pdf) is pretty good, take a look at *6.6.10 Filtering Warning Messages*:

> To instruct the static contract checker not to emit a particular class
>   of warnings for a method (a type, an assembly), annotate the method
>   (the type, the assembly) with the attribute:
>
> ```
> [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Contracts", warningFamily)]
> ```
>
> where warningFamily is one of: `Requires, Ensures, Invariant, NonNull,
>   ArrayCreation, ArrayLowerBound, ArrayUpperBound, DivByZero,
>   MinValueNegation`.
>
> If necessary,  the static contract checker allows filtering a single
>   warning message (instead of an entire family) as well. To do so you
>   can annotate a method with the attribute
>
> ```
> [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Contracts", warningFamily-ILOffset-MethodILOffset)]
> ```
>
> where `warningFamily` is as
>   above, and `ILOffset` and `MethodILOffset` are used by the static
>   contract checker to determine the program point the warning refers to.
>   The offsets can be obtained from the static contract checker by
>   providing the -outputwarnmasks switch in the "Custom Options" entry in
>   the VS pane. Check the Build Output Window for the necessary
>   information.

Comment: Look like no one has any ideas about #1, so I guess this takes the accepted answer!